# Cannot drop constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Not having luck when dropping a constraint...I am logged in as 'sa' which should have enough permissions to execute it but I still get:

```
Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot find the object "dbo.Products" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

And here is the query:

```
USE [PRSS10_DATABASE]
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
      FROM sys.foreign_keys 
       WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.FK_Product_SMC')
       AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Products')
    )
      ALTER TABLE [dbo.Products] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_SMC]
```

Now I am able to access the table.. the table exists and the Foreign key as well.. what could I be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the brackets.  when you do `[dbo.products]` that makes it think the whole object is named **"dbo.products"**  What you want is `[dbo].[Products]` so that it recognizes **"dbo"** as the *schema* and **"Products"** as the table *name*.

Comment: nice to see I'm not the only one who does this :)

Answer (score 2):

Fix the statement to read like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] DROP CONSTRAINT [dbo].[FK_Product_SMC]
```